# Shorten if Statement Actionscript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, if-statement

I just started learning actionscript and I'm wondering how could I shorten this if statement

```
if (txtInputTemp.charAt(track - 1) == "a" || txtInputTemp.charAt(track - 1) == "b" || txtInputTemp.charAt(track - 1) == "c" || txtInputTemp.charAt(track - 1) == "d" || txtInputTemp.charAt(track - 1) == "e" || txtInputTemp.charAt(track - 1) == "f" || txtInputTemp.charAt(track - 1) == "g" || txtInputTemp.charAt(track - 1) == "h" || txtInputTemp.charAt(track - 1) == "i" || txtInputTemp.charAt(track - 1) == "j" || txtInputTemp.charAt(track - 1) == "k" || txtInputTemp.charAt(track - 1) == "l" || txtInputTemp.charAt(track - 1) == "m" || txtInputTemp.charAt(track - 1) == "n" || txtInputTemp.charAt(track - 1) == "o" || txtInputTemp.charAt(track - 1) == "p" || txtInputTemp.charAt(track - 1) == "q" || txtInputTemp.charAt(track - 1) == "r" || txtInputTemp.charAt(track - 1) == "s" || txtInputTemp.charAt(track - 1) == "t" || txtInputTemp.charAt(track - 1) == "u" || txtInputTemp.charAt(track - 1) == "v" || txtInputTemp.charAt(track - 1) == "w" || txtInputTemp.charAt(track - 1) == "x" || txtInputTemp.charAt(track - 1) == "y" || txtInputTemp.charAt(track - 1) == "z" || txtInputTemp.charAt(track - 1) == "." || txtInputTemp.charAt(track - 1) == "'" || txtInputTemp.charAt(track - 1) == "-" || txtInputTemp.charAt(track - 1) == " ") { }
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can rewrite a-z to range specification.

```
somechar>="a" && somechar<="z"
```

But I have no idea how to shorten these symbols.

```
== "."
== "'"
== "-"
== " "


var somechar:String = txtInputTemp.charAt(track - 1);
if ((somechar>="a" && somechar<="z")||somechar == "."||somechar == "'"||somechar == "-"||somechar == " ")
{
    // do something
}
```

Working Example: http://wonderfl.net/c/A9Hv

**Option2:** Use [array.indexOf(char)](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Array.html#indexOf%28%29) == -1 or not.

```
var someArray: Array = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z",".","'","-"," "];

var somechar:String = txtInputTemp.charAt(track - 1);

if (someArray.indexOf(somechar) != -1)
{
    // Do something
}
```